# To Convert Base64 URL to Base64 Encoded format in WSO2 EI 6.3.0

Tags: base64, gmail-api, base64url

I am getting email attachment(images) from [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) which returns **base64url encoded string**. But actual encoded is different from this gmail api("/" is replaced by "_" and "+" is replaced by "-" etc). I want to get original base64 encoded string instead of base64 url encoding format. Shall i replace that two symbols("/","+") from gmail api response or can anyone please help me to achieve this? i am trying this using WSO2 EI 6.3.0.

```
 <call>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http method="get" uri-template="{+uri.var.gmail.apiUrl}/{+uri.var.gmail.apiVersion}/users/{+uri.var.gmail.userId}/messages/{+uri.var.id}/attachments/{+uri.var.attachmentId}"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
 <property description="emailAttachment" expression="//data/text()" name="emailAttachment" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

for eg,

**from Gmail API :**  after that call, it returns following value in "data" key.

> _9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD_4QBMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAAqACAAQAAAABAAAPwKADAAQAAAABAAAL0AAAAAD_....

**original Base64 Encoded value:**

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBMRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAAqACAAQAAAABAAAPwKADAAQAAAABAAAL0AAAAAD/....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 decoding of MIME email not working (GMail API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812139/base64-decoding-of-mime-email-not-working-gmail-api)

Comment: No, It's not. I am expecting Base64 Encoded value. I need to convert base64url encoded value which comes from gmail api to base64 encoded value.

Comment: And did you actually read it?

Comment: In which language do you want to perform the conversion?

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka,
I am performing this operation in WSO2 EI. for that i have include the way i get base64url Encoded string from gmail for attachment. so i need to complete this in WSO2 EI. i can use script also. for eg. `<script language="js"><![CDATA[var log=mc.getServiceLog();
    var emailAttachment = mc.getProperty('emailAttachment'); emailAttachment=emailAttachment.replaceAll("_","/").replaceAll("-","+");
    log.info("Modified Content is:" + emailAttachment);
    mc.setProperty("modifiedemailAttachment",emailAttachment)]]></script> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In Javascript the easiest would be to use the [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

`newData=data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')`

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka,
if i tried the above in my script mediator, it'll through exception like `ERROR - ScriptMediator The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: The choice of Java method java.lang.String.replace matching JavaScript argument types
 (function,string) is ambiguous; candidate methods are:
    class java.lang.String replace(char,char)
    class java.lang.String` in addition to that, **if i replace that two symbol, will it work for all cases?**

Comment: I am not sure what your variable `data` is. `replace()` is a method that expects a string as parameter. I do not see any reason why it should not work in all cases.

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka,
i am also checking the same. but above mentioned replaceAll() is works fine.
**emailAttachment** in above is base64url encoded string. what i need to do is i want to get base64 encoded string from base64 url encoded value?if i just replace that two symbol which will work for all cases(ie.conversion from base64url to base64 encoded)?

Comment: Yes.  `+` and `/` for `toBase64` versus `-` and `_` for `toBase64URL` are the only differences.

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka,
I have done for converting from base64url encoded into base64 encoding format by replacing both symbol which works fine. Thanks for your support

Comment: @Justin, I am glad it helped! If you found my answer useful, I would appreciate if you could mark it as accepted.